# Android: Change delay before the phone is put to sleep while my app is running

Tags: android, sleep

This question sounds so easy I can't believe I can't find information on it (maybe I have the wrong key words in mind...)

I'm looking for a way to change the delay before the phone is put to sleep when my app is running.

I was using wake locks until now to prevent my app from being closed to frequently (its and opengl app and the loading time is a killer specially on slow phones).
I don't like the idea of indefinitely leaving the phone on (mainly because it empties the battery fast to have a full opengl app running).

Is there a way then to change the delay before the phones goes to sleep to 2~3min ?

I would also like to add that I do not wish to change the settings of the phone (that is only the users decision)

Jason

edited to correct the term "application going to sleep" which was pointed out as being incorrect.

Comment: This is up for the user to decide (in the system settings). If anything, you could consider removing the wake lock after n minutes, but are you sure you want to override the user settings?

Comment: No, form my opinion I shouldn't even be wasting time on this, unfortunately my boss has been putting this back on the todo list for a long time (and I can't keep ignoring it lol)

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense.  An app isn't "put to sleep" ever.  The phone might go to sleep.  An activity can be paused and put into the background if the user opens a different activity.  If the activity is in the background, the Android OS might decide to kill it if it needs to resources, but there is nothing you can do to prevent that.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Is there a "clean" way of removing a wakelock after n minutes ? (I mean something already coded in the api not just a "make a thread wait n minutes then have it remove the wake lock" type of solution ?

Comment: @ Mayra: sorry if I wasn't clear/making sense (I only had 2 h sleep because of the jetlag :(. if you don't touch your phone, for a certain time it "goes to sleep" (screen goes black and you have to unlock it when you wake it up etc.). what I want to know is "Is there a way to control this time it takes before the phone is put to sleep when my app is open"

Comment: @Jason Rogers Ok, so you want to prevent the phone from going to sleep for a certain amount of time.  That makes sense, sort of.  Shouldn't the user's interaction with the game prevent it from going to sleep anyways though?  Or is it a game where you are staring at the screen for a long time not touching it?

Comment: p.s.  When you do @name don't put a space in between, that seems to prevent the notification magic.

Comment: There is not so much staring at the screen but while testing the application we often ended up having the phone go to sleep while thinking ^^ (enough for my boss to find it annoying)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `Timer` object and `release()` your wake lock in the timer task. I'm relatively sure you can release a lock in a worker thread, but worst case, you'd need to use `runOnUiThread` if I'm incorrect.

Be sure to handle the case when `onPause()` is called and cancel your timer in that case and release the lock immediately.

In general, I'm not a fan of wake locks, but if this is to make your boss happy, wake-lock away.

EDIT: Btw, the system setting for the UI timeout is accessible by apps: `SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT` in `android.provider.Settings.System`. But really, this is for private applications only, public applications have no business changing this value.

Comment: It seems like the timer should get reset everytime the user interacts with the screen though.  Also, if you do this you should provide a way for the user to configure the amount of time, or turn off the wakelock entirely.

Comment: Yep, I'll leave the finer details to Jason. That's just the first thing that came to mind. I still think it's a terrible UI hack (Android has a system setting for that!), but by the sound of it, this is for a private application, so they can hack all they want.